# C# Regular Expression Markers in XML

Tags: c#, regex

I have a text which looks like this:

> "\xee\x80\x80nike\xee\x80\x81: \xee\x80\x80\x46ind\xee\x80\x81 your \xee\x80\x80greatness\xee\x80\x81. (uk) - youtubeis \xee\x80\x80nike\xee\x80\x81 purposefully making fun of a boy trying to \xee\x80\x80\x66ind\xee\x80\x81 ..."

I need to remove the markers like \xee\x80\x81 or \xee\x80\x82 etc

I am using the following regular expression `\\xee\\x[0-9][0-9]\\x[0-9][0-9]`.  It is not working but if I use `\\xee\\x80\\x81` it works. I want a general expression since the number could be anything.

Could someone please tell me what the problem is?

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried?

Comment: var resultFinal = htmlContent_lower.Replace("\\xee\\x80\\x80""); This removes \xee\x80\x80 but when I try  var resultFinal = htmlContent_lower.Replace("\\xee\\x[0-9][0-9]\\x[0-9][0-9]""); it does not remove it

Comment: Isn't that chars a reference for unicode characters? Would be better try to extract some info from them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously problem is here `\xee\x80\x80\x46` - chars `\x80` repeats twice and then `\x46`, so it doesn't match your pattern.

You can try `\\xee(\\x[0-9][0-9])+` pattern - it will remove any occurences `\xee` followed by one or more`\x[0-9][0-9]`.

Or you can use `\\xee(\\x\d{2})+` - it is basically the same but looks more elegant from my point of view. Here `d` stands for "any digit" and `{2}` for "exactly two times", and `()+` is "group occured one or more times"

```
var result = Regex.Replace(your_text, @"\\xee(\\x\d{2})+", "");
```

Result for your sample will be:

> nike: ind your greatness. (uk) - youtubeis nike purposefully making fun of a boy trying to ind ...